# Regex string location in parsed string

Tags: c++, regex

This is going to be in some pseudo code because I am unsure how to do parts of this.

What I am trying to do is search through a string with a regex_iterator.  But I would like to find where the location of the found sub string is and not the actual string itself.  I am hoping I can just do this through the regex_iterator itself and not have to use string::find type functions.

```
file.open("file.mac", ios_base::in|ios_base::out);
if (!file) return 1;

char input_char;
string file_text;
string style_parse;

while (file >> noskipws >> input_char) {
        file_text += input_char;
        if (input_char == '\n') {
            style_parse += '\n';
        }
        else {
            style_parse += 'A';
        }
    }

regex re("([${]{2})([[:w:]]+)([}])");

sregex_iterator pos(file_text.begin(), file_text.end(), re);
sregex_iterator end;

// the location of search_text in file_text.  Could also be a string
// iterator too
size_t string_location = 0;
// going to be pos->str(0) in the for loop;
string search_text;

for (; pos != end; ++pos) {
    // Loop thru pos and get the location of each sub string.  Use
    // the location to replace values in style_parse.  IE replace 'A'
    // with 'B'
}
```

Is there a way to do that through the iterator or am I going to have to use string::find for each sub string found?

The files I am parsing look like this.  Its basically just a text file.

```
 :Loop
/if ( ${MacroState.NotEqual[MAINLOOP]} ) {
  /varset OldMacroState ${MacroState}
  /varset MacroState MAINLOOP
}
/doevents
/if (${Me.Dead}) /call Wait4Rez
/if (!${EQBC.Connected}) /bccmd reconnect
|**/if (${Me.Invis}) /goto :Loop**|

/call AssistMA
/if (${DebuffList.Count[[]}) {
  /if (${DoDebuff}) /call Debuff
  /if (${Spawn[${MATarget}].PctHPs}<${WhenToBurn} && ${NameList.Find[${Spawn[${MATarget}].CleanName}]}) /call BurnName
  /if (${DoHeal}) /call CheckGrp
  /if (${DoCure}) /call CheckCureGrp
  /call Mana
} else /if (${MobList.Count[[]} && !${DebuffList.Count[[]}) {
  |**|/echo MobList: ${MobList} |-| DebuffList: ${DebuffList} -- ${DebuffList.Count[[]}**|
  /if (${DoHeal}) /call CheckGrp
  /if (${Spawn[${MATarget}].PctHPs}<${WhenToBurn} && ${NameList.Find[${Spawn[${MATarget}].CleanName}]}) /call BurnName
  /if (${DoNuke}) /call Nuke
  /if (${DoDoT}) /call DoT
  /if (${DoPanther}) /call Panther
  /if (${DoHeal}) /call CheckGrp
  /if (${UsePet}) /call Pet
  /if (${DoCure}) /call CheckCureGrp
  /if (${DebuffedList.Count[[]}) /call CheckDebuffs
  /call Mana
} else /if (!${MobList.Count[[]}) {
  /if (${DoHeal}) /call CheckGrp
  /if (${DoCure}) /call CheckCureGrp
  /call Mana
  /if (!${UnSlowedAdds} && !${Me.Casting.ID}) {
    /if ( ${UsePet} ) /call CheckPetBuff
    /if (${DoWild} && !${WildTimer}) /call CheckWild
    /call CheckSelfBuff
    /doevents
    /if (${QueueCount}) /call DoBuffEvents
  }
  /if (${Defined[MobList]} && ${MobList.Length}) /deletevar MobList
  /if (!${Defined[MobList]}) /declare MobList string outer
}
/if (${Cursor.ID}) /autoinventory
/if (${DoLoot} && ${Me.CombatState.NotEqual[COMBAT]}) /call LootMobs
/if (${Spawn[${MATarget}].Dead} || ${Spawn[${MATarget}].Type.Equal[NULL]}) /varset MATarget 0
/if (${DoLeash} && !${DoLeashToon}) /call Leash
/if (${DoLeashToon}) /call DoLeashPerson
/if (!${CheckExpTimer}) /call AutoAdjustExp
/call UpdateMobList
/goto :Loop
```

As always thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally figured it out and it was a lot easier than I was expecting.  Love having one of those brain dead coding moments.  Here is the code inside the for loop if anyone in the future wants to do something like this.

```
for (; pos != end; ++pos) {
    smatch match = *pos;
    string search_text = match.str();
    size_t string_location = match.position();

    //f(string) is just a lambda to pad out the proper amount of 'B'
    string replace_text = f(search_text);

    style_parse.replace(string_location, search_text.length(), replace_text);
}
```